# Setting MAGMOM in VASP for possible Magnetic configurations

Tags: vasp, magnetism

I have been working with a material in which Cu has an unpaired electron due to which the material can exist in various magnetic configurations. I wish to see how various properties change as I switch between Antiferromagnetic and ferromagnetic configurations. Due to this I have been running spin polarized calculations and have been setting MAGMOM tag accordingly.

Till now my MAGMOM tag looked something like `MAGMOM = 16*0 8*0 2 -2 2 -2 32*0` where I was assigning 0 to all the atoms which did not have unpaired electrons and `-2` and `2` based on the configuration. The final magnetization obtained can be seen below where 25,26,27 and 28 are actually Cu atoms and the atoms which are directly bonded to them also posses some magnetic moment as can be seen below(I confirmed that these are the molecules bonded with Cu only due to which we observe polarization)

[image]

For different magnetic configurations we vary the initial magnetic moment of Cu atoms, but what about the atoms which do not possess any unpaired electrons??

Speaking from a theoretical point of view the spin up and down should cancel each others so should we take the initial magnetic moment(which is specified by MAGMOM tag in vasp) to be equal to zero when no unpaired electrons can be found for example - Sb +3.

My main question is that - Should we take the initial magnetic moment = 0 for atoms with unpaired electrons.

Some pointers to take into consideration:

- The material is quite new so I do not have any experimental data about magnetic moments
- If we take the spins of all the atoms into consideration we will have to analyse a lot more anti ferro and ferro magnetic configurations into account than have been described in earlier works(they only talk about varying the spin of Cu)
- I tried using some different MAGMOMs by giving initial magnetic moments to atoms with unpaired electrons but the calculation failed and in a similar fashion as has been described [here](https://www.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18458).

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it's been 6+ months, I wonder if you've made any progress on this, figured out an answer, or if you're still working on this? Please update us!